# Profiling CherryPy application with dowser

Tags: python, profiling, cherrypy

I have one question about dowser usage. 
I created my own web site based on CherryPy and there is a memory leak but I don't know where it is. After searching information about my problem I understood that dowser is a great tool which can tell where the memory leak happens.

So, in [usage tutorial](https://github.com/Infinidat/dowser) there are some steps that help to integrate dowser in existing CherryPy app, but I don't understand where can I see a result of memory usage? How should I use trace and chart variables?

Thanks!

Comment: From the tutorial you linked it looks like it mounts /dowser, /trace and /chart to your app. Have you visited those URLs in your browser yet?

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't touch `trace` and `chart` if you have properly mounted the `dowser` app to your CherryPy tree. It could be something as follows. Run, wait a minute and find the leak on /dowser (psst, look at instance count charts).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os
import threading
import time

import cherrypy
import dowser


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 4
  }
}


class DowserToShow:
  pass


class App:

  issueIsMe = []
  exited    = False
  thread    = None


  def __init__(self):
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target = self.leak)
    self.thread.start()

    cherrypy.engine.subscribe('exit', self.exit)

  def exit(self):
    self.exited = True
    self.thread.join()

  def leak(self):
    while not self.exited:
      for i in range(100):
        self.issueIsMe.append(DowserToShow())
      time.sleep(1)

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return 'Leaked instances, {0}'.format(len(self.issueIsMe))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.tree.mount(dowser.Root(), '/dowser')
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```